# Get current TextBox Text value in a button onClick event - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, textbox, onclick, controls

I have such a page

```
<form runat="server" id="NewForm">
    Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="AddNewName" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="AddNewName_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="NewName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

In the code behind, I have a Page_Load which assign a value to the TextBox Name.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name.Text = "Enter Your Name Here";
}
```

Then upon the Click on the button AddNewName, I will write it in the Label NewName

```
protected void AddNewDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewName.Text = Name.Text;
}
```

But, no matter what I input in the Name TextBox, the Label only displays "Enter Your Name Here". It never updates to the actual content in the Name TextBox. What am I doing wrong with this code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you are always overwriting the changed value in `Page_Load`. Instead, check the `IsPostBack` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        Name.Text = "Enter Your Name Here";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are `re-assigning` the text to Name every time `Page_Load` that over writes the text you entered in TextBox before reach `AddNewDivision_Click` event. To assign it once on page load and do not over write the subsequent calls you can use `Page.IsPostBack` property.

```
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      Name.Text = "Enter Your Name Here";
```

Or you can assign the text in design html and `remove` the `statement` from `page_load`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text="Enter Your Name Here"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I wish I could select both of your answers. But Tim was the first answer and his answer solved this issue. Sorry Adil. But I've voted up for yours too.

Comment: So nice of you @TheJinStudio. Its perfectly al-right, Thanks for care.

Answer (score 0):

Another immediately obvious issue is:

```
<form runat="server" id="NewForm">
    Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="AddNewName" runat="server" Text="Add" **OnClick="AddNewName_Click"** />
    <asp:Label ID="NewName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Not the asterisks above.  Then, you were wondering why this didn't run:

```
protected void **AddNewDivision_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewName.Text = Name.Text;
}
```

Again, note the asterisks.  You weren't calling the correct void, in fact you were probably calling a void that didn't even exist.